# Rails: How to determine size of http response the server delivers to the client?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, http, gzip

I am running a Rails 3.2.2 app on Ruby 1.9.3 and on my production server i run a Phusion Passenger/Apache Server.

I deliver a relatively huge amount of data objects in JSON format which contain redundant data from a related model and I want to know how many bytes the server has to deliver and how the redundant content can be gziped by the server and how the redundant data influences the size of the http response that has to be shipped.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have data that is not needed, you should first look in to how to get rid of that data in the response, rather than compressing it.

Comment: removing the data would complicate the format of the json and it would be a lot of computing overhead removing the data and parsing the inconstant object format.

Comment: "A lot of computing overhead" would be small for encoding JSON; I reckon that compression would take more cycles than JSON encoding. I like to use JSON views using gems such as [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) or [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder). There's a nice [Railscast on RABL](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl). Most importantly: why waste your user's bandwidth on redundant data?

Comment: the JSON represents actual objects and I don't want to break up the objects structure to reduce the possible redundancy because the object mapping on the client side will be a lot more complex to implement. Thanks for the link to RABL I heard about it but i am currently using the [acts_as_api gem](https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api) which is also doing a good job but i will definitely take a closer look at RABL as i continues to expand my API capabilities!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know in general how much data is being sent, use curl or wget to make the request and save to a file -- the size of the file is (approximately) the size of the response, not including the headers, which are typically small.  gzip the file to see how much is actually sent over the wire.

Even cooler, use the developer tools of your favorite browser (which is Chrome, right?).  Select Network tab, then click the GET (or PUT or POST) request that is executed and check things out.  One tab will contain the headers of the response, one of which will likely contain a `Content-Length` header, assuming your server is set up to gzip, you'll be able to see how much compression you're getting (compare uncompressed to the Content-Length).  The timings are all there, so you can see how much time it takes to get a connection, for the server to do the work, for the server to send back the data, etc.  Brilliantly cool tools for understanding what's really happening under the covers.

But echoing the comment of Alex (capital A) -- if you're sending a ton of data in an AJAX request, you should be thinking of architecture and design in most cases.  Not all, but most.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i know about the possibilities of analyzing things with chrome which is indeed my favorite browser ;) I just thought it would be nice if the size of the content delivered is logged by rails or apache on each request.
i don't load the data over ajax because my client is not a web browser.

Comment: Some additional information:
I now found out that gzip/mod_deflate is not activated on apache by default so here is how to [activate it].

(http://trevorturk.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/speed-up-your-apachepassenger-rails-app-in-2min/)
It really decreases the size of my responses by a factor of 10 even if all the redundant data is removed!

But I am really looking a solution with allows me to monitor the amount of transfered data caused by a specific API over a larger timespan